How to make my contract run on the bsc test network
I released a LD liquidity through Pancake, which is BSC test network and USDT, but I don't know how to get the corresponding route and pair in the code. I would like to ask,

Is my route different from the test network? There is a BSC route address on the cake document
How do I get my pair? My block is https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x4829c5dd07459bb38b7b37f2109e1269919879f6834273c7432dc9da38123441

I have a project contract, which I released to the BSC test network, but the setup code contains some route and pair settings, and I don't know how to set them.
I tried some answers from gpt, such as
  const factoryAddress = "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73";
  const abiPath = path.join(__dirname, 'IUniswapV2Factory.json');
  const factoryABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(abiPath, 'utf-8'));
  const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factoryAddress,factoryABI.abi,singer);
  const all =  await factoryContract.allPairsLength();
  console.log("all:",all)

the file from
https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-core@1.0.0/build/IUniswapV2Factory.json

It will directly report an error message saying
reason: 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string',
code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
data: '0x',

Thank you

I tried many ways, such as
const bscTestnetProvider = new JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-testnet.blockpi.network/v1/rpc/public');
const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factoryAddress,factoryABI.abi,bscTestnetProvider);

But it still doesn't work, basically all errors are reported:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 44,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "execution reverted"
    }
}


You can see your pair created in transaction log PairCreated https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x4829c5dd07459bb38b7b37f2109e1269919879f6834273c7432dc9da38123441#eventlog
As I see, your pair is located at  0xbE90A53A3f5972DF8412C29D8100D6Cbd5152a15

Is my route different from the test network?

I see the contract was verified and many transactions recently. I believe this route is true
